# Changing the file name causes issue

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel VBA code does not work if change the file name please make changes in the code whatever my file name it works.
Details

I make a code based on the file but I change the file name it is showing me an error.

[image]

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
    
    
    Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
    
    
    Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
    
    
    
    Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
    
    
    
    Range("F2:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
```

My Excel VBA code does not work if change the file name please make changes in the code whatever my file name it works.
Details
I make a code based on the file but I change the file name it is showing me an error.

Comment: "showing me an error" = what specific error is it showing you?

Answer (score 0):

The code is trying to activate a workbook named "File1.xlsx". If you change that filename, the code cannot find a workbook named "File1.xlsx", and that will produce an error.

If you want the code to activate the workbook that contains the code, you can use `ThisWorkbook` instead of the filename.

Instead of `Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate` try `ThisWorkbook.Activate`

A better approach would be to assign a workbook variable and refer to the variable throughout your code. This makes it easier to update the code later.

```
Dim wb As Workbook  'Declare a workbook variable

Set wb = ThisWorkbook   'Assign the workbook to the variable

wb.Activate 'Activate the workbook
```